# Can't run the cpde

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

```
       <script>
        var firstname = "John";
        var lastname = "Doe";
        var totalname = firstname +lastname ;
        var d = new day();
        document.getElementById("something").innerHTML  = d ;
        document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = totalname;
```

Nothing is shown , Only if I remove

```
var d = new day();
        document.getElementById("something").innerHTML  = d ;
```

JohnDoe can be shown then .Why this happen?Help appreciated

Comment: [Please avoid superfluous profanity in posts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites).

Comment: @Alexander Nied Im sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `new day()` class in javascript.

use this, it will give you day in digit from current date

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
```

Comment: document.getElementById("something").innerHTML  = Date.getDay();

Comment: it should be `new Date().getDay()`